# How to make character move when holding down key in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Right now, I have this:

```
for event in pygame.event.get(): 
   if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
        done = True 
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    # moves hero with key presses 
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] == 1:
        hero.goLeft()
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] == 1:
        hero.goRight()
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP] == 1:
        hero.goUp()
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] == 1:
        hero.goDown()
```

However, I'm still having to press the key multiple times to move the character. Does anyone know why or have a different solution?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you have to change `key repeating`. I usualy use `event.KEYDOWN` and `event.KEYUP` to start and stop moving (`move_left = True`, `move_left = False`) and after events `if move_left: hero.goLeft()`. Some example in class [Player](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/pygame/__templates__/1__simple__.py)

Answer (score 0):

`keys = pygame.keys.get_pressed()` and the following lines should not be inside of the event loop, otherwise it's called only once for each event that gets added to the event queue and you won't get continuous movement. Just dedent these lines.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        done = True

keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
# moves hero with key presses
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    hero.goLeft()
elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    hero.goRight()
if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
    hero.goUp()
elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    hero.goDown()
```

You can also just check `if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:` instead of `if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] == 1:`.